# Windows Azure Backup more than 3 times a day

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, azure

Windows Azure Backup Scheduler currently restricts the backup operation to a maximum of 3 times a day ([as explained here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/systemcenter/archive/2014/05/08/using-and-monitoring-azure-backup-for-windows-server.aspx)). However, I found that the created task shows up in the task scheduler where you can schedule more backup times.

Anybody already try that or is there some restriction, i.e. recovery services only accepting 3 operations per day?

Comment: What do the Terms of Service say about it? Something being technically feasibly is worthless if your service agreement forbids it.

Comment: Tried it anyway and now the schedule does not run at all, even though I've removed the extraneous operations and re-entered the scheduling data thru Windows Azure Backup